# What's an "auto SA" for ESXi's IPsec command "esxcli network ip ipsec sa remove"?

Tags: vmware-esxi

The help for `esxcli network ip ipsec sa remove` mentions *auto SA* but I failed to find any info from Google.

```
[root@j2-ceriqv-050:~] esxcli network ip ipsec sa remove --help
Usage: esxcli network ip ipsec sa remove [cmd options]

Description:
  remove                Operation to remove Security Association(s)

Cmd options:
  -a|--remove-all       Set to remove all Security Associations.
  -d|--sa-destination=<str>
                        Ipv6 address of Security Association destination. This option needs to be
                        specified when removing an auto SA.
                                                   ^^^^^^^
  -n|--sa-name=<str>    Name for the Security Association to be removed. Specify 'auto' to remove an
                        auto SA.
                        ^^^^^^^
  -s|--sa-source=<str>  Ipv6 address of Security Association source. This option needs to be specified
                        when removing an auto SA.
                                         ^^^^^^^
  -p|--sa-spi=<str>     SPI value for the Security Association (hex). This option needs to be specified
                        when removing an auto SA
                                         ^^^^^^^
```

The `esxcli network ip ipsec sa add` command does not mention *auto SA*:

```
[root@j2-ceriqv-050:~] esxcli network ip ipsec sa add --help
Usage: esxcli network ip ipsec sa add [cmd options]

Description:
  add                   Add a Security Association.

Cmd options:
  -e|--encryption-algorithm=<str>
                        Encryption algorithm for the Security Association. Should be one in set  [null,
                        3des-cbc, aes128-cbc]. (required)
  -k|--encryption-key=<str>
                        Encryption key(ASCII or hex). Length of hex key is dependent upon algorithm
                        used. Required when a encryption algorithm has been specified.
  -i|--integrity-algorithm=<str>
                        Integrity algorithm for the Security Association. Should be one in set
                        [hmac-sha1, hmac-sha2-256]. (required)
  -K|--integrity-key=<str>
                        Integrity key(ASCII or hex). Length of hex key is dependent upon algorithm used.
                        (required)
  -d|--sa-destination=<str>
                        Ipv6 address of Security Association destination. Can be specified as 'any' or a
                        correct IPv6 address. (required)
  -m|--sa-mode=<str>    Security Association mode. Should be one in set  [transport, tunnel].
  -n|--sa-name=<str>    Name for the Security Association to be added. (required)
  -s|--sa-source=<str>  Ipv6 address of Security Association source. Can be specified as 'any' or a
                        correct IPv6 address. (required)
  -p|--sa-spi=<str>     SPI value for the Security Association(hex). (required)
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [`network ip ipsec sp add`](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vcli.ref.doc%2Fesxcli_network.html) includes the following:

> --sa-name | -a
>   Name for the Security Association. **Not being Specified lets vmkernel automatically choose an Security Association**. If no applicable Security Association exists, then vmkernel may request one using IKE.

<sub>(highligting by me)</sub>

So, you need to provide `--sa-name=auto` when you want to remove a SA that has been chosen automatically earlier.